# Export sheets with formulas in only few columns and rest as values

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using Mr Ron De Bruin's code to export multiple sheets into a separate workbook and attach to Outlook mail:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail3.htm

This code contains an option to send only values. However, I would like to keep formulas in a few columns ex: J, E in Sheet1 and keep values only in the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to account for OP's different needs

I'd go like follows:

---

If column E, J formulas *restriction* applies to *all* worksheets

```
    Dim col As Range

    For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
        For Each col In sh.UsedRange.Columns
            If col.Column <> 5 And col.Column <> 10 Then col.Value = col.Value
        Next
    Next
```

---

If column E, J formulas *restriction* applies to *"Sheet1" worksheet only*

```
    Dim col As Range

    For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
        If sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
            For Each col In sh.UsedRange.Columns
                If col.Column <> 5 And col.Column <> 10 Then col.Value = col.Value
            Next
        Else
            With sh.UsedRange
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
```

Comment: Hello, I am able to see only the values without any formulas in all the columns. I would like to have only values in all the columns except for columns E & J. For these two columns I would like to retain their formulas from the original sheet. Please let me know if you need additional information. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: the code does what you asked for in your question: _"keep formulas only in a few columns ex: J,E in Sheet1 and keep values only in rest all columns"_. If your need doesn't match what you wrote then edit/enhance your question properly and I'll try and edit my answer accordingly. If the columns J and E formulas issue is to apply for all worksheets, then state it clear.

Comment: Hi, the code given by you is pasting all the columns with values including the columns E & J. I would like to retain the formulas just for E & J and paste the values for the other columns. I asked the same in my questions as follows: "However, I would like to keep formulas only in a few columns ex: J,E in Sheet1 and keep values only in rest all columns."

Comment: Your question example says _"...J,E in Sheet1 ..."_. So my code keeps formulas in columns E and J for "Sheet1" worksheet only. See edited answer where I added a code to act on _all_ worksheets

Comment: Hello user3598756! Thank you very much for your answer. It works like a charm. Exactly what I wanted :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Paste the full worksheet as values and thereafter the Range you want to be passed as formulas with a full Paste. That will replace the values. Pasting ranges is fast. You can afford a double paste.

```
'Change all cells in the worksheets to values if you want
Dim tmpWS As Worksheet
For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
    Set tmpWS = Destwb.Sheets.Add
    sh.Select
    sh.Range("E:E").copy Destination:=tmpWS.Range("E:E") 
    sh.Range("J:J").copy Destination:=tmpWS.Range("J:J") 
    With sh.UsedRange
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).Select
    End With
    tmpWS.Range("E:E").copy Destination:=sh.Range("E:E") 
    tmpWS.Range("J:J").copy Destination:=sh.Range("J:J") 
    tmpWS.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Next
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the revert. I initially got a compile error as "For without Next". So, I inserted a "Next sh" at the end of the given code by you.But now, I am getting a Run time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method and it is highlighting ".cells.Paste". Please advice how to mitigate this error

Comment: First off, this code **won't do what OP's wanted to** since first `Copy`-`PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` would overwrite all formulas with their corresponding results, thus making subsequent `Copy`-`PasteSpecial` ineffective for the purpose of leaving formulas in place. While as for the `Run time error '438'`, its because there's no `Paste` method for `Range` object, while there's `PasteSpecial()`

Comment: user3598756 was right, sorry for my mistake. You need to cache the cells first - The code I posted first did overwrie the formulas. And, obviously, the Next statement was missing. See my new edit.